# Append new request example to drf-spectacular schema

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg, drf-spectacular

I know the way to add examples for the schema used by drf-spectacular is:

```
examples=[
            OpenApiExample(
                'Example 1',
                description='longer description',
                value='example'
            ),
        ]
```

However, instead of creating from scratch the examples, I would like to add a new one to the one that is automatically generated.

Is there a way to do this? Or at least, generate the request body fro the serializer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

drf-spectacular does **not** generate examples by itself. Uunless you provide `OpenApiExample` instances. the schema will not contain examples. If you see an example it is because your UI (swagger/redoc) came up with one based on the given types. I assume they stop doing this once you provide an actual example.

I think that makes sense once you indicate that you take care of your examples yourself. In any case it would be a setting in the UI as this has nothing to do with spectacular.